# android load sqlite data in fragment

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments

I'm getting problem that cannot load sqlite data in Fragment as follow

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment {

    DatabaseUtil dbUtil = new DatabaseUtil(this.getActivity());
    private ArrayList <HashMap<String, Object>> getNews;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list, container, false);


        new LoadNewsLists().execute("");        

        return v;
    }
```

Here is loading data from sqlite

```
Cursor cursor = dbUtil.fetchAllData(arg[0]);
```

following error is encountered.

```
03-08 12:21:52.900: E/AndroidRuntime(25895): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-08 12:21:52.900: E/AndroidRuntime(25895):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
```

Comment: Make sure you are excessing db only in one thread

Comment: try this  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    new LoadNewsLists().execute("");
    }

Comment: sorry, same error occurred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't init your db object in the same time when define it. You should move initialisation code to `onCreateView()` callback :

```
DatabaseUtil dbUtil ;
private ArrayList <HashMap<String, Object>> getNews;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list, container, false);

    dbUtil = new DatabaseUtil(getActivity());
    new LoadNewsLists().execute("");        

    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's going on inside `DatabaseUtil(this.getActivity())` constructor, but you shouldn't rely on the Activity being fully initialized until you reach the `Fragment.onActivityCreated()` callback.